# firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7059 after 45000 ms

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have developed Selenium script using selenium java webdriver (wrote and complied on windows machine). I extracted the automation suite as executable jar and placed it on Linux (`RHEL 6.4`). When i log in Linux desktop (GUI) and try to run the suite `(java -jar Automation.jar)`, the test suite kicks up fine. Now keeping the GUI unlocked, when i try to run the same command using ssh from my windows machine, i am getting error - `"firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7059 after 45000 ms"`

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the two steps followed at the same time looking for workaround.

Comment: Did you redirect the X display?

Comment: No i haven't. How can i redirect x display?